# separating out the array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am going through an object and separating out the array in customer and customerportals but my code is not working

```
var j=0;
var k = 0;
var myVar[j][k] = Array();

$.each(Object.customer, function(index, value) { 

    $.each(value.portal.customerPortal, function(innerIndex, innerValue) { 

        myVar[j][k] = innerValue.name;
            k++;

        });
        j++;
    });

    alert(myVar[0][0]);
```

any help would be great

Comment: Did you really assign a `customer` property to `Object`? Also don't use `Array()`, use `[]`.

Comment: "Is not working" is not enough.

Comment: Javascript is to Java as car is to carpet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array declaration syntax is wrong (even, C-like!).

```
var myVar = [];

$.each(Object.customer, function(index, value) { 

    var newElm = [];
    $.each(value.portal.customerPortal, function(innerIndex, innerValue) { 
        newElm.push(innerValue.name);
    });

    myVar.push(newElm);
});

alert(myVar[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is not Java. The syntax to declare an array is: `someVariable = []`

So:

```
var j=0;
var k = 0;
var myVar = [];
myVar[j] = [];
```

Which creates an array, containing one element at index 0 (which is another array)

Comment: how do i make it 2 dimenssional? I am confused

Comment: I guess I am trying to find how to get the values of myvar[j][k] out then and use them

Comment: @Autolycus: You don't. Javascript is not typed in that manner. You just add arrays as elements.

Comment: @Autolycus `([['foo'],['bar']])[1][0]` -> "bar" Note that it is one operator `[index]`, applied twice, to two different objects (the array containing the two arrays, and then the array containing 'bar'), just like in Java (neither Javascript nor Java have true n-dimensional arrays).